# What type of inputs are accepted by netlogo procedures

Tags: input, matrix, parameters, procedure, netlogo

Is it possible in NetLogo to create procedures that have parameters of type matrix.
If yes, please let me know how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create procedures with any type of argument.  If you want real matrices, you'll need to use the `matrix` extension, which is described in the user manual.  For example:

```
extensions [matrix]

to-report my-row [row mat]
  report matrix:get-row mat row
end
```

Here `my-row` isn't really useful, since it just does what `matrix:get-row` does, but it illustrates the idea.  Then you can do things like this:

```
show my-row 2 (matrix:make-identity 3)  ==>   [0 0 1]
```